# Split a string into pieces using java / a better code

Tags: java, regex

I have to split this string:

```
00016282000079116050
```

It has predefined chunks. Should be just like that:

```
00016 282 00 0079 116 050
```

I made this code:

```
String unformatted = String.valueOf("00016282000079116050");
String str1 = unformatted.substring(0,5); 
String str2 = unformatted.substring(5,8);
String str3 = unformatted.substring(8,10);
String str4 = unformatted.substring(10,14);
String str5 = unformatted.substring(14,17);
String str6 = unformatted.substring(17,20);

System.out.println(String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %s", str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6));
```

It works, but I need to make this code more presentable/prettier.

Something with Java 8 streams or regex should be good. Any suggestions?

Comment: Streams = why/how? Regex = maybe if you know the pattern of the string values you are extracting. Basically, there is nothing wrong with slicing the string.

Comment: Even if it's a  bit hard to write, using substring isn't a bad way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more [java](/questions/tagged/java) oriented way would be to use a loop and an array of predefined lengths.

```
int[] lims = {5,3,2,4,3,3};
int total = 0;
String original = "00016282000079116050";

for (int i = 0 ; i < lims.length ; i++) {
    System.out.print(original.substring(total, total+=lims[i]) + " ");
}
```

### Output

```
00016 282 00 0079 116 050
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use a regular expression to compile a `Pattern` with 6 groups, something like

```
String unformatted = "00016282000079116050"; // <-- no need for String.valueOf
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{5})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{4})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(unformatted);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s", m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), 
            m.group(4), m.group(5), m.group(6));
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
00016 282 00 0079 116 050
```

**Or**, as pointed out in the comments, you could use `Matcher.replaceAll(String)` like

```
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.replaceAll("$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6"));
}
```

Comment: Did you just use the `String.valueOf` to make it flexible for other objects?

Comment: Since you choose to use a regex, why not to perform a replacement instead of using a formatted string?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thank you for your help. It's exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That's another good option; thanks. Edited.

Comment: However, if it is only for displaying, it doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Of course, if this is a one-time operation, there is no need to deal with `Pattern` and `Matcher` explicitly, a simple `System.out.println(unformatted.replaceFirst("(\\d{5})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{4})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})", "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6"));` will do…

Answer (score 0):

```
        String unformatted = "00016282000079116050";
        int[] splittingPoints = new int[]{5,3,2,4,3,3};
        int charactersProcessed = 0;
        int howManyBeforeSplit = 0;
        int chunksDone = 0;
        for (char c : unformatted.toCharArray()) {
            if ((charactersProcessed++ - chunksDone) == splittingPoints[howManyBeforeSplit]) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                chunksDone += splittingPoints[howManyBeforeSplit++];
            }
            System.out.print(c);
        }
```